# Printing all the words from a prefixtree in order

Tags: c++, class, pointers, recursion, pointer-to-member

I've set up a program that can take in user input to create a prefixtree. Each character is a node which are linked together. I have a "print" command that will print the words out as the following if the user gave this input: cat, car, sat, saw:
ca(R,T),sa(T,W).

I'm trying to create two functions that will instead print out the words given from the user in alphabetical word. One function `PrintAllWords()` is the function that will be doing most of the work, I'm thinking of having this function be a recursive function that would print to a global string of some sort each word through `push_back()` then delete that current word from pull_back() and move onto the next. The second function `printWordList()`; would call `printAllWords()`; and just print out the list of words create.

I've start with some code trying to slowly get to where I want, but at the moment when I use the command "list" (the command for the new functions) my code only gives me the parent nodes C and S as the following: cs.

How can I just get the first nodes of each word, try and get the first word in the prefixtree being "cat".

My Header File:

```
#ifndef __PREFIX_TREE_H
#define __PREFIX_TREE_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;

class PrefixTreeNode;

/*
  Prefix tree
  Stores a collection of strings as a tree
 */
class PrefixTree
{

private:
  PrefixTreeNode* root;
public:
  //Constructs an empty prefix tree
  PrefixTree();
  //Copy constructor
  PrefixTree(const PrefixTree&);
  //Copy assignment
   const PrefixTree& operator=(const PrefixTree&);
  //Utility func: checks whether all characters in str are letters
  bool isAllLetters(const string&) const;
  //Returns the root of the prefix tree
  PrefixTreeNode* getRoot() { return root; };
  //Returns the root of the prefix tree
  const PrefixTreeNode* getRoot() const { return root; };
  //Returns whether or not the given word belongs to the prefixtree
  bool contains(const string&) const;
  //Adds the given word to the prefix tree
  void addWord(const string&);
  //Prints all of the words in the prefix tree
  void printWordList() const;
  //Destructor
  ~PrefixTree();
};

/*
  Node of a prefix tree
 */
class PrefixTreeNode
{
  friend PrefixTree;
private:
  char c;
  bool final;
  PrefixTreeNode* link[ALPHABET_SIZE];
public:
  //Constructs a new node
  PrefixTreeNode();
  //Copy constructor
  PrefixTreeNode(const PrefixTreeNode&);
  //Copy assignment
  const PrefixTreeNode& operator=(const PrefixTreeNode&);
  //Returns the character this node contains
  char getChar() const { return c; }
  //Returns whether this node is the end of a word
  bool isFinal() const { return final; }
  //Changes whether this node is the end of a word
  void setFinal(bool b) { final = b; }
  //Returns the node corresponding to the given character
  PrefixTreeNode* getChild(char);
  //Returns the node corresponding to the given character
  const PrefixTreeNode* getChild(char) const;
  //Adds a child corresponding to the given character
  void addChild(char);
  //Removes the child corresponding to the given character
  void deleteChild(char);
  //print all words that end at or below this PrefixTreeNode
  void printAllWords() const;
  //Destructor
  ~PrefixTreeNode();
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const PrefixTree&);
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const PrefixTreeNode&);
#endif
```

My Source File functions:

```
void PrefixTreeNode::printAllWords() const{

for (char c = 'a'; c < 'z' + 1; c++)
    {
      if (this->getChild(c) == nullptr)
        continue;

        this->getChild(c);
      cout << c;
    }

}

//Calls all words
void PrefixTree::printWordList() const{

    PrefixTreeNode* node = root;
    node->printAllWords();
}

PrefixTreeNode* PrefixTreeNode::getChild(char c)
{
  if (isalpha(c))
    return link[tolower(c)-'a'];
  else
    return nullptr;
}

void PrefixTree::addWord(const string& str)
{
  PrefixTreeNode* node = root;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
  {
    if (node->getChild(str[i]) == nullptr)
      node->addChild(str[i]);
    node = node->getChild(str[i]);
  }
  node->setFinal(true);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all symbols beginning with double-underscore (like e.g. `__PREFIX_TREE_H`) are *reserved* and should not be defined as preprocessor or other symbols by programs. Please see [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: As for your problem, I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on the `printAllWords` function. What is it really doing?

Comment: On a slightly related note, not all character encodings have letters consecutively encoded. ASCII have, but there are other possible encodings still being used (for example [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC)) where a loop like your over the letters won't work.

Comment: You may want to use recursion in your print code.

Comment: How does the tree have *one* root? Which character is in that root?

Answer (score 3):

We use recursion to print all the stored strings in the tree in order. Call the function from main using `printAllWords(root, "")`. If `root` points to `nullptr`, we return. If `root->final` is `true`, we print the word. Then we append the current character to `word` and loop through all it's children and call `printAllWords` for each of them.

The same will happen for every node.

```
void printAllWords(Node* current, std::string word)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return;

    if (current->final)
        std::cout << (word+current->c) << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
        printAllWords(current->link[i], word + current->c);
}
```

Edit: Although I must confess I'm not sure what's the use of `c` in the treenode. If you construct the trie such that if let's say the 2nd child (`b`) of the current node is not null, then that means that `b` is part of a trail of another word(s) through it. The following code should make it clear:

```
void printAllWords(Node* root)
{
    string word = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
        printAllWords(root->link[i], word + (char)(i + 'a'));
}

void printAllWords(Node* current, std::string word)
{
    if (current == nullptr)
        return;

    if (final)
        std::cout << word << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; ++i)
        printAllWords(current->link[i], word + (char)(i + 'a'));
}
```

Comment: Why? What makes your code work? Please try to explain it, so it doesn't become just another promotion of [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) with an easy to do copy-paste that the OP might not know how or why it works.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I'll edit the code. Thank you.